# File download from http site fails with error, "System.IO.IOException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

File download from HTTP site fails with error,

> "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\python-3.8.0-amd64.exe' because it is being used by another process".

```
url = "http://ip:43/installer/python-3.8.0-amd64.exe"
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
filename = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1];
installer_path = $@"c:\Temp\{filename}";

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   client.DownloadFile(url, installer_path);
   client.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: im guessing its "*because it is being used by another process*", what do you think?

Comment: I have run it for the first time, not sure which file is using before it is downloaded. May be any other method

Comment: Or your antivirus.

Comment: It could be virus scanner, try restarting pc, also, you can use SysInternals, ProcessMon, or FileMon or something to see which program it is

Comment: Restart didn't help

Comment: I suggest you save it as `*.tmp file`, so: `installer_path = $@"c:\Temp\{filename}.tmp";` and check if that solves your issue. If it does, then it's probably antivirus scanning a downloaded executable. You can rename the file after the download is complete.

Answer (score 1):

1. check if the file available on the location
2. Check **MIME** configuration in **IIS**
3. Check the **access rights** to the destination also

```cs
client.DownloadFileCompleted += WcOnDownloadFileCompleted;

private static void WcOnDownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //async download completed successfully
    }
    handle.Set(); // in both the case let the void main() know that async event had finished so that i can quit
}
```

Comment: Yes, its available. I can download the file using powershell

Comment: try to implement DownloadFileCompleted  for WebClient

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Task manager
2. Go To Processes Tabs
3. Search for "python-3.8.0-amd64.exe" in list
4. If its there then right click on it and select End Task
5. Now run your code, it should be fine